# iPhone Goes To Sleep While Navigating

Tags: iphone, sleep-wake

This is a new thing my phone does since I believe iOS 12. Is there any way to stop it?

I use turn-by-turn navigation on my phone all the time. But these days, the phone tends to go to sleep in the middle of my trip. It used to never do this. The phone would always stay fully awake while navigating. But now my phone goes black and I have to hit the home button to wake it up and go back to the map.

The phone is plugged in to power while all this is going on. 
This "feature" is new and is a huge pain in the ass. Is there any way to go back to the previous behavior?

Comment: Can you check if you have Low Power mode active?

Comment: I definitely do not and never have. I don't generally run out of battery during the day and I charge every nice, AND my phone is plugged in when it's in my cradle navigating.

Answer (score -1):

If you go to settings/Display & Brightness/Auto-Lock and set this to never, that should work?

Hope this helps

Comment: Sorry, that's not at all helpful. Of course I can shut off display sleep all together. I want to specifically turn it off JUST while navigating. The behavior that was default for a decade. Having to navigate through preferences to turn off display sleep entirely, then remember to turn sleep back on when I'm done navigating, every time, is not a solution to this problem.

Comment: Ah ok I guess that was my bad for misunderstanding the question, sorry Im no help :(